# How to close the connection using Promise.all in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, neo4j, promise

I am using neo4j driver in NodeJs to connect to its database. However, I am getting -

```
Neo4jError :socket hang up
```

When searched for the solution, it says that I am closing the driver before the queries are finished. But I don't have any `driver.close()` or `session.close()` in my code. How can I resolve the error?

**app.service.js**

```
        const neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;
        const driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://" + neo4jIP + ":" + 
        neo4jPort, 
        neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "abc"));
        var session = driver.session();


                       for (i = 0; i < cyphers.length; i++) {


                                queries.push(session.run(cyphers[i]));
                                console.log("after session.run , 
                                CYPHERS, cyphers[i] ", cyphers[i]);


                                Promise.all(queries)
                                    .then(function (results) {

                                        results.forEach(function (result) {

                                        })

                                    })
                                    .catch(function (err) {
                                        console.log("inside catch = " + err);
                                    })
                                    }
```

queries object is -

> after session.run , CYPHERS, cyphers[i]  Match
>   (txnstatus_18:txnstatus_18) where txnstatus_18.name ='txnStatus_18'
>   Create  (subject_18:subject_18{name:'subject_18',company:'abc'}),
>   (txnstatus_18)-[:Parameter]->(subject_18)
>
> after session.run , CYPHERS, cyphers[i]  Match (return_18:return_18)
>   where return_18.name ='return_18' Create 
>   (wfbolckinfo_2:wfbolckinfo_2{name:'wfBolckInfo_2',company:'abc'}),
>   (return_18)-[:Parameter]->(wfbolckinfo_2)
>
> after session.run , CYPHERS, cyphers[i]  Match
>   (wfbolckinfo_2:wfbolckinfo_2) where wfbolckinfo_2.name
>   ='wfBolckInfo_2' Create  (targetactivityid_2:targetactivityid_2{name:'targetActivityId_2',company:'abc'}),
>   (wfbolckinfo_2)-[:Parameter]->(targetactivityid_2)

Comment: what is in your queries object?

Comment: hi gnusey, i added the queries object.

Comment: @Techdive You added the console log entries, not the `queries` object. Also, the `Promise` code should execute *after* the `for` loop; you currently have it exeuting inside the loop. Fixing your indentation should also help to make your code more readable. In addition, your question's title seems not to reflect what you are actually asking about.